# Способ получить скорость мобильной сети и ее dBm

Tags: android, kotlin, сеть, iphone

Почему все методы которые есть для этого помечены как Deprecated,

```
telephonyManager.listen(
                object : PhoneStateListener(){
                    override fun onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength: SignalStrength) {
                        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength)

                        val dbm = if (signalStrength.isGsm) {
                            if (signalStrength.gsmSignalStrength != 99)
                                signalStrength.gsmSignalStrength * 2 - 113
                            else
                                signalStrength.gsmSignalStrength
                        } else {
                            signalStrength.cdmaDbm
                        }

                        val type = when(telephonyManager.phoneType){
                            TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM -> "GSM"
                            TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA -> "CDMA"
                            TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_SIP -> "SIP"
                            else -> "NONE"
                        }

                        _state.value = _state.value.copy(
                            dbm = "$type $dbm"
                        )
                    }
                },
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS
            )
```

а новый метод доступен только с 12 android

```
(context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as? TelephonyManager)?.
        registerTelephonyCallback(
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
            object :  TelephonyCallback(), TelephonyCallback.SignalStrengthsListener {
                override fun onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength: SignalStrength) {
                    val mSignalStrengths = signalStrength.cellSignalStrengths.map { it.dbm }
                    func(mSignalStrengths.sum() / mSignalStrengths.size)
                }
        )
```

что естественно не подходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  telephonyManager.listen(
            object : PhoneStateListener() {

                override fun onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength: SignalStrength) {
                    super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength)

                    _state.value = _state.value.copy(
                        dbm = "${getSignalStrengthByName(signalStrength, "getDbm")}"
                    )
                }

                private fun getSignalStrengthByName(
                    signalStrength: SignalStrength,
                    methodName: String
                ): Int {
                    return try {
                        val classFromName = Class.forName(SignalStrength::class.java.name)
                        val method = classFromName.getDeclaredMethod(methodName)
                        val any = method.invoke(signalStrength)
                        any as Int
                    } catch (ex: Exception) {
                        -1000
                    }
                }
            },
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS
        )
```

и получаем dBm